# Kernel disconnecting on Google Colab with the error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, nifti

I am having trouble with theses disconnections, kernel keeps interrupting and restarting. I am trying to figure out why since earlier this day and I still don't get it.

The code uses a re-implementation in Python, which can de found here [https://pypi.org/project/brainextractor/](https://stackoverflow.comhttps://pypi.org/project/brainextractor/)

I installed it in the Jupyter Notebook and it did run for the first 8 NIfTI images, but now it stopped working even without changing anything in the code, I did switch the system output audio to a bluetooth speaker meanwhile, and I noticed that there are some errors in the logs regarding ALSA lib, but does that even make sense?

It raises this warning everytime kernel is restarted: error:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
```

I tried to reconnect plenty of times, I changed the environment to one with a GPU 85 GB RAM, but it is still not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.